# How to link to VTK library on Windows using g++

Tags: vtk, mingw32

I want to use the command line to compile a simple program using the VTK library:

```
g++ -IC:\VTK\Install\includes\vtk-5.10 SimpleTest.cpp -LC:\VTK\Install\lib
\vtk_5.10 -lvtkCommon -lvtkGraphics
```

SimpleTest.cpp

```
#include "vtkConeSource.h"

int main()
{
    vtkConeSource* cone = vtkConeSource::New();
    cone->SetHeight(5.0);   
    return 1;   
}
```

but I always get many errors about "undefined references". For example:

C:\VTK\Install\lib\vtk_5.10/libvtkGraphics.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.obj):vtkConeSource.cxx:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `vtkInformationVector::GetInformationObject(int)'

C:\VTK\Install\lib\vtk_5.10/libvtkGraphics.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.obj):vtkConeSource.cxx:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline::MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_PIECES()'

C:\VTK\Install\lib\vtk_5.10/libvtkGraphics.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.obj):vtkConeSource.cxx:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `vtkInformation::Set(vtkInformationIntegerKey*, int)'

C:\VTK\Install\lib\vtk_5.10/libvtkGraphics.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.obj):vtkConeSource.cxx:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `vtkPolyDataAlgorithm::PrintSelf(std::ostream&, vtkIndent)'

C:\VTK\Install\lib\vtk_5.10/libvtkGraphics.a(vtkConeSource.cxx.obj):vtkConeSource.cxx:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, vtkIndent const&)'

and many more ...

I can't tell if I am using wrong syntax for g++ or if there is something wrong with my VTK library.

I am using:
VTK 5.10.1

minGW 4.7.2, 32 bit

VTK was compiled from source with minGW using CMake 2.8.11.2

update:
I did find this tutorial http://vtkblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/build-vtk-from-source-using-mingwmsys.html about this. However I used minGW32-make instead of installing MSYS and using it's "make". Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: I recommend that you use CMake to generate your makefile for your application. CMake will handle the library dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

As a very first test, try explicitly including all vtk libraries contained in Install\lib\vtk_5.10 - to ensure those undefined references are not coming from those missing libraries.